# Making Stage static in javaFX. is it a good idea?

Tags: java, static, javafx, stack, stage

I actually want to build a fx application that go from one fxml to another (with this process :fxml number 1 load then go with a click  and another load).

I have made stage in my main class static and use it again and again.

according to Restriction of stack space in ram is it a good idea ?? or there is a better way?

these are parts of my code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static Stage stage;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    stage=primaryStage;
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainWidget.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Welcome");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    stage.show();
}
```

and my controller is(loading another fxml!! )

```
public void someButtonController{
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/ShowWidget.fxml"));
            Scene scene =  new Scene(root,300,300);

            Main.stage.setScene(scene);
            Main.stage.show();}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not expose the `Stage` at all. Doing so couples your FXML-Controller pair to your `Main` class and prevents you ever using it without that class.

Instead, do something like

```
@FXML
private Button someButton ;

// ...

public void someButtonController{
    Window window = someButton.getScene().getWindow();
    if (window instanceof Stage) {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/ShowWidget.fxml"));
        Scene scene =  new Scene(root,300,300);
        Stage stage = (Stage) window ;
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show(); // isn't it necessarily showing already?
    }
}
```

Here I'm assuming that the controller is the controller for an FXML file representing `Node`s that are displayed in the `Stage` you're trying to access. If that's not the case, you can still do something similar though it will be more complex.